# Disable add to cart redirection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Now, hitting the "add to chart" button on the archive page will add product to cart, but will also redirect custommer to the page of certain product, and I am trying to disable any redirection after hitting "add to cart" button. I want custommer to stays at the same page where he has been before hitting the button, or just to "refresh" page after adding to cart.

Any suggestions?

```
/**
 * Redirect subscription add to cart to checkout page
 *
 * @param none
 */
function add_to_cart_checkout_redirect() {
        wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink( get_option(
           'woocommerce_checkout_page_id' ) ) );
        die();
  }
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',  'add_to_cart_checkout_redirect', 11
);
```

Comment: Where Is your Code for this???

Comment: @JunaidAhmed code added

Comment: By default, adding to cart from the archives page is done via ajax and shouldn't refresh the page at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer. If you want custom redirection, there is a filter for that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_redirect_function' );
    function custom_redirect_function() {
    return get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[image: WooCommerce Settings]

WooCommerce by default provides the setting for you. Just check if this solution fits your requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot, You saved my time @WisdmLabs

Answer (score 8):

Try to use wp_get_referer as shown

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wp_get_referer' );
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This was the right solution for me: To stay on the same page after add-to-cart .

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code to the file functions.php

```
/**
 * Set a custom add to cart URL to redirect to
 * @return string
 */
function custom_add_to_cart_redirect() { 
    return 'http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/'; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' );
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. How can I replace "http://www.yourdomain.com/your-page/" with a page where custommer was when he clicked at the "add to cart" button?

Thanks

Comment: You can add the page where you perform the add to cart itself. So it will redirect to same page.

Comment: No, problem is that I need to stay at the same archive or product page, where I pushed "add to chart" button

Comment: Then i think you can give the product page url like $url = get_permalink( $product_id ); and get the current product page url and give there.

Comment: This is what's happening now. When I add to cart it redirects me to the product page, but I need to stop any redirection.

Comment: Did you get the current product page with product name or product id. Then try to give that there.

Answer (score 0):

Use remove action

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',  'add_to_cart_checkout_redirect', 1);
```

Comment: Does not work, still redirecting me to the page of certain product

Comment: make sure add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',  'add_to_cart_checkout_redirect', 11
);   is causing the redirection . comment it and check  . I think it should redirection to the checkout page not the product page