# WooCommerce - Change Add to cart URL

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Product Bundles, and at the end of the product there is an Add to Cart button. Clicking it refreshed the page, and adds the addons to the cart. I want to change the URL to a different page, instead of just refreshing it.

Here is the button's HTML code:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button bundle_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

Comment: You can change from woocommerce settings and can redirect user directly to checkout page.

Comment: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/#display - scroll down and look for `Add to Cart` behavior

Comment: @cale_b Ok, though I want them to go to /custom-page/ not the cart. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable add to cart redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998060/disable-add-to-cart-redirection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it correctly, you want to redirect to different page after the add to cart action done right.?

If that is the case put this on your `functions.php`

```
function redirect_after_add_to_cart( $url ) {
    return esc_url( get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Your Page Title' ) ) );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_after_add_to_cart', 99 );
```

Comment: You are truly a life saver