# Wordpress Woocommerce add to cart behaviour

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi so i'm building something like a online shop website using woocommerce and every time i clicked on the add to cart button it keeps redirecting me to the cart page which i know there is an option on it. but i make sure every time that it was not checked.

So, why am i keep getting redirected to cart page every time i click add to cart even though i already disable the option to redirect?

this is what i've tried so far : restarting, checking the ajax option, disable and enable woocommerce

Comment: This looks like a [duplicate of this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998060/disable-add-to-cart-redirection)

Comment: i tried all 5 answers and none works for me